# Erro ao deletar arquivo com unlink

Tags: php, codeigniter

Como fazer para remover um arquivo com unlink?

o arquivo está nesta pasta

```
/home/user/public_html/public/data/file.png
```

eu estou executando o unlink a partir desse arquivo

```
/home/user/public_html/admin/application/controllers/delete.php
```

Estou usando codeigniter, ou seja, `/admin/` tem um *codeigniter* e a `public_html` tem outro

Sempre que tento remover ele da esse erro

[image: Erro]

Comment: Basta ler a mensagem de erro: "Não existe tal arquivo ou diretório". Você pode até estar vendo ele no diretório mas **aos "olhos" da Aplicação**, no caso o arquivo que executa o unlink() ele não pôde ser localizado. Edite sua pergunta com mais informações para tentarmos te ajudar com o debug.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao stackoverflow, uma dica, não use imagens para colocar mensagens de erro na questão, e coloque o código que ocorre o erro aqui também. Leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique antes se o arquivo existe utilizando o comando `file_exists`

O código ficaria algo assim:

```
if(file_exists($caminho_para_arquivo)){
    unlink($caminho_para_arquivo);
}
```

Mais informações aqui: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-exists.php